# Prime NG carousel displays two rows after setting autoplayInterval props even I set the numVisible to 1

Tags: angular, angular-material, tailwind-css, server-side-rendering, primeng

I'm using PrimeNG v17 on the Angular 17 project.
While working with the carousel, I have weird issue.
`numVisible` prop work well in non-autoplay mode.
But once I set `autoplayInterval` props, it shows 2 rows.

```
<p-carousel [value]="carousels" [numVisible]="numVisible" [numScroll]="1" orientation="horizontal" [circular]="true"
  [showNavigators]="false" [autoplayInterval]="3000" (onPage)="onPageChange">
  <ng-template let-carousel pTemplate="item">
    <div class="w-full h-[560px] bg-cover flex flex-col justify-end"
      [style.backgroundImage]="'url(' + '../../../../assets/images/' + carousel.img + ')'">
      <!-- some contents here -->
    </div>
  </ng-template>
</p-carousel>
```

As you can see in the above code part, there should be only one row on the carousel but it displays two rows.
Here is the brief `HTML Dom` after it was built.

```
<div class="p-parousel-items-content">
  <div class="p-carousel-items-container">
    <div class="p-carousel-item">
      <!-- slide 1 -->
      <!-- slide 1 -->
    </div>
    <div class="p-carousel-item">
      <!-- slide 2 -->
      <!-- slide 2 -->
    </div>
    <div class="p-carousel-item">
      <!-- slide 3 -->
      <!-- slide 3 -->
    </div>
    <div class="p-carousel-item">
      <!-- slide 4 -->
      <!-- slide 4 -->
    </div>
    <div class="p-carousel-item">
      <!-- slide 5 -->
      <!-- slide 5 -->
    </div>
    <div class="p-carousel-item">
      <!-- slide 6 -->
      <!-- slide 6 -->
    </div>
    <div class="p-carousel-item">
      <!-- slide 7 -->
      <!-- slide 7 -->
    </div>
    <div class="p-carousel-item">
      <!-- slide 8 -->
      <!-- slide 8 -->
    </div>
    <div class="p-carousel-item">
      <!-- slide 9 -->
      <!-- slide 9 -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

There should be only one slide part in each div with `p-carousel-item` class, but there are two duplicated slides.
I have tried this but it's also not working.

```
.p-parousel-items-content
  .p-carousel-items-container
  .p-carousel-item:nth-child(2) {
  display: none;
}
```

Please let me help if anyone has experience with this issue and resolved it.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Its due to the `flex` properties you have configured, please remove the flex classes and this will resolve your issue, here is a working example with the same configurations as your question and its working fine.

If you are still not ok with this answer, please share back the stackblitz with the same issue replicated!

[primeng carousel demos](https://primeng.org/carousel)

```
<div class="card">
  <p-carousel
    [value]="products"
    [numVisible]="1"
    [numScroll]="1"
    orientation="horizontal"
    [circular]="true"
    [showNavigators]="false"
    [autoplayInterval]="3000"
  >
    <ng-template let-product pTemplate="item">
      <div
        class="border-1 surface-border border-round m-2 text-center py-5 px-3"
      >
        <div class="mb-3">
          <img
            src="https://primefaces.org/cdn/primeng/images/demo/product/{{ product.image }}"
            [alt]="product.name"
            class="w-6 shadow-2"
          />
        </div>
        <div>
          <h4 class="mb-1">{{ product.name }}</h4>
          <h6 class="mt-0 mb-3">{{ '$' + product.price }}</h6>
          <p-tag
            [value]="product.inventoryStatus"
            [severity]="getSeverity(product.inventoryStatus)"
          ></p-tag>
          <div
            class="mt-5 flex align-items-center justify-content-center gap-2"
          >
            <p-button icon="pi pi-search" [rounded]="true" />
            <p-button
              icon="pi pi-star-fill"
              [rounded]="true"
              severity="secondary"
            />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </ng-template>
  </p-carousel>
</div>
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/wixexb?file=src%2Fmain.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fdemo%2Fcarousel-basic-demo.html)

Comment: Hi @Naren. I have tried what you suggested but it's not working.
I have updated my question. Please check it again and let me know what the issue is.
Thank you

Comment: @Benjamin please share a stackblitz with the share issue replicated on the question, I will validate!

Comment: Great. I will share it asap.